# SQL where clause with multiple criteria in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, where-clause

Struggling a bit with this seemingly easy SQL query. How can I query a table so that it returns values that are either NULL OR after a certain date? Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM data 
AND Operational_End_Date IN (NULL, > '2022-08-01')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `OR`:

```
select *
from data 
where operational_end_date is null 
   or operational_end_date > date '2022-08-01'
```

Note: assuming that `operational_end_date` is of the `date` datatype as its name seems to imply, you would compare it against a literal date rather than a string.

You could also phrase it with `coalesce`, as in:

```
select *
from data 
where coalesce(operational_end_date, date '9999-12-31') > date '2022-08-01'
```

The idea is to turn `null` values to a far future date (here, `'9999-12-31'` is the greatest date that BQ supports), so they pass the inequality condition.

Comment: That's perfect - thanks, GMB!